# Inputting the amount you want displayed in the array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, exception

I am writing a program that displays integer arrays. I set the size of the array, but I am wondering how I can ask the user the index of the array that they want listed. Say the **const SIZE = 10**, and the user wants to see the first three in the array. I want to also write an **exception** that catches the error if the user input is over the size of the array. If you need to see some code, let me know. Any help is appreciated!

intergerarray.h

```
class IntArray
{
private:
    int *aptr;                     // Pointer to the array
    int arraySize;                 // Holds the array size
    void subscriptError();         // Handles invalid subscripts
public:
    class OutOfBoundException
    {
    public:
        int index;
        OutOfBoundException(){};
        int getInde() { return index; }

    };
    IntArray(int);                 // Constructor
    IntArray(const IntArray &);    // Copy constructor
    ~IntArray();                   // Destructor

    int size() const               // Returns the array size
    {
        return arraySize;
    }

    int &operator[](const int &);  // Overloaded [] operator
};
```

IntergerArray.cpp

```
IntArray::IntArray(int s)
{
    arraySize = s;
    aptr = new int[s];
    for (int count = 0; count < arraySize; count++)
        *(aptr + count) = 0;
}


IntArray::IntArray(const IntArray &obj)
{
    arraySize = obj.arraySize;
    aptr = new int[arraySize];
    for (int count = 0; count < arraySize; count++)
        *(aptr + count) = *(obj.aptr + count);
}


IntArray::~IntArray()
{
    if (arraySize > 0)
        delete[] aptr;
}


void IntArray::subscriptError()
{
    cout << "ERROR: Subscript out of range.\n";
    exit(0);
}


int &IntArray::operator[](const int &sub)
{
    if (sub < 0 || sub >= arraySize)
        subscriptError();
    return aptr[sub];
}
```

driver file.cpp

```
    int main()
{
    int SIZE = 10;
    //int index;
    //cout << "enter an index";
    //cin >> index;
    IntArray table(SIZE);

    for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++)
        table[x] = x;

    for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++)
        cout << table[x] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    //table[SIZE + 1] = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please provide the code you tried.

Comment: @Billa Updated the question with the code. I made a nested class that is supposed to determine index and create an exception for my problem. I am not entirely sure on how to do so.

Comment: accept and upvote an answer if you think it should help any one in future

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to display all elements lower than an index value entered by the user :

Let array[] be the array name of size=10,you can get an index value (say `l`) from the user and use that value inside a `for loop` for printing all elements in index lower than `l`

```
 int array[size] 
void disp_in(int l)
  {
   if(l>=size) // if l greater than or equal to size (as index start at 0)
      throw l;
   else
       {

        cout<<"Elements : ";
        for(int i=0;i<=l;i++) //if we have say l=2 ,array values in indexes 0,1and 2 will be displayed
            cout<<array[i];

         }
    }
int main ()
      {
       int l;
       cout<<"Enter index : "; 
       cin>>l;  //till this index value, the array value will be displayed
       try
          {
           disp_in(l);
            }
       catch(int e)
          {
          cout<<"Index value greater than max index"; 
            }
         return 0;
         }
```

Comment: please tell me was this what you need

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I tested it, it displays 0 for however large the user input is. I need the other for loops to display the array which shows 0-9 so I kept the same code but added what you suggested and that is what the outcome was.

Comment: Definitely you are quick to respond and helpful. Unfortunately, the upvote wont show for me but I left it :)

Comment: Now it is perfect please check it and accept ( click the tick near top left of answer) .

Comment: I am using an object to access the array. Displaying the array like: 
cout <<  array[i] makes the argument missing. Also l is undefined in main  because it is defined as the parameter in the void function.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what you are trying to do? why so much code for such a simple problem?

```
    const int arraySize = 10;
    int array[arraySize];

    int elementToDis;
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Number of array elements to display: ";
        std::cin >> elementToDis;
    } while (elementToDis > arraySize || elementToDis < 0); // this is your exeption

    for (int ccc(0); ccc < elementToDis; ++ccc)
        std::cout << "Index " << ccc << ": " << array[ccc] << '\n';
```

Comment: I am practicing classes and exceptions. 
int array[SIZE] needs to be an object not an interger. So doing a while loop in that manner wont work. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

void print_numbers( const std::vector<int>& array, int nNumbers, const char* pszSeparator )
{
    if ( nNumbers > static_cast<int>(array.size()) )
    {
        throw std::exception();
    }

    std::copy( array.begin(), array.begin() + nNumbers, std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, pszSeparator ) );

}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> array( 10 );

    //Just for testing
    {
        int n = 0;
        auto generator = [n]() mutable
        {
            return n++;
        };
        std::generate_n( array.begin(), array.size(), generator );
    }

    try
    {
        print_numbers(array, 11, "\n");
    }
    catch ( std::exception e )
    {
        std::cout << "Error message..." << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```